# NA in Conditional coverage test for VaR backtest

Tags: time-series, garch

I have 3000 observations of *MSFT.ret* where I take log return of microsoft stock from 2000 to 2012.

I specify a normal garch(1,1) model in `garch11.spec` and then do a rolling window

```
MSFT.garch11.roll.500.5 = ugarchroll(garch11.spec, MSFT.ret, n.ahead=1,
                                     forecast.length = 500, refit.every=5, 
                                     refit.window="moving")
```

Note that I put the forecast.length and refit.every in the name of the object.

In `report(MSFT.garch11.roll.500.5, type="VaR")` I  accept H0 of Kupiec's test which is good. **But for the test of Conditional Coverage (Christoffersen) I get NaN**. What did I do wrong?

I try to specify with other such as

```
report(MSFT.garch11.roll.500.1,   type="VaR")  
report(MSFT.garch11.roll.500.5,   type="VaR")  
report(MSFT.garch11.roll.1000.20, type="VaR") 
report(MSFT.garch11.roll.2000.40, type="VaR") 
report(MSFT.garch11.roll.2000.20, type="VaR")
```

but for all I get *NaN*. Why?

Comment: Could resolve this issue? I have the same problem and don't know how to handle it, too.

Comment: Answered my own question.

Answer (score 2):

**Reason**: Because you have too few violations. Recall that the test is based on violations that are binary. This is very little information. If the size of your forecasting window is 500 and you have a 1% VaR then you expect 5 violations. Let's say 3 occurred. This is too little information to perform the hypothesis testing.

**Handle it:** There are different ways

- accept it and move on
- increase the VaR level e.g. from 1% to 5%
- increase the forecasting window size e.g. from 500 to 1000
- do another test such as the *berkowitz test* or a *VaR duration test* (both are available in the rugarch package if you google on the italicized words + rugarch). this works because those test utilize more information---there is great loss when binarizing.